# Azure Data Factory V2: auto-start trigger upon deployment?

Tags: templates, deployment, triggers, factory

I created a pipeline and a trigger, and I'm trying to get the trigger to be auto-started right after deployment.
I saw in documentation that after deployment the trigger's state is "stopped" and I want to ask how can I change that in my template deployment in order to not be needed to use powershell script right after every deployment.

I tried to use the "runtimeState" parameter in my TD but it was replaced to "stopped".

This is my trigger:

```
 {
      "name": "[concat(variables('factoryName'), '/periodicTrigger')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "properties": {
        "description": "Periodic trigger for the backup pipeline.",
        "annotations": [],
        "runtimeState": "Started",
        "pipelines": [
          {
            "pipelineReference": {
              "referenceName": "[concat(variables('mainStorageName'),'backupPipeline')]",
              "type": "PipelineReference"
            },
            "parameters": {}
          }
        ],
        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
          "recurrence": {
            "frequency": "Day",
            "interval": 1,
            "startTime": "2018-08-21T13:28:07.785Z",
            "timeZone": "UTC",
            "schedule": {
              "minutes": [
                0
              ],
              "hours": [
                3
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/pipelines/',concat(variables('mainStorageName'),'backupPipeline'))]"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: Anyone? trigger seems to be a new feature of data factory V2. In V1, it was automatically when deployed a pipeline.

Comment: Same issue here, also tried setting "runtimeState" but to no avail. The ARM docs also don't mention anything that would indicate that this is possible :-/

Only found these powershell cmdlet to enable it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/start-azdatafactoryv2trigger

Would love to do that from within the ARM template though...

Answer (score 5):

It's not supported yet, 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues/1583

"
After investigating the issue, unfortunately there is no way to create an activated trigger. ARM templates only support PUT actions, but start is a separate POST action. To activate a trigger, you must explicitly call the start API either via UX, Powershell or whatever ADF SDK you are using after creation. This is due to runtime state being a readonly property that a user cannot explicitly set.
"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little [PowerShell](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2021/11/adf-release-use-script-to-enable.html) instead or set the endTime property via the ARM template to something in the past (but not before startTime) to disable it and to something in the future to enable it.